# how to replace multiple word to a single word in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Basically I have a string of:

```
var str = "aaaa aaa aaaaaa safsd a a a aaaa";
```

**Note:** `a` could be `x` times,

I need to replace all `a`s connected together to a single `a`, for Example replace `aaaa` to `a` and the output that I need from above `str` should be something like:

Output:
`a a a safsd a a a a`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`string.replace(regexp, newString)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and use `/a+/g` to match one or more `a`'s.

```js
var str = "aaaa aaa aaaaaa safsd a a a aaaa";

str = str.replace(/a+/g, "a");

console.log(str)
```

Comment: watch out for multiple a's within another word if you don't want those converted to a single 'a'. In that case use word boundary `\b` in your regex: `"aaa saafsd a aaa".replace(/\ba+\b/g, "a")`

Comment: @spencerWieczorek You answer absolutely worked, Although this is irrelevant But can you also do this on java, i am having a bit of issue in my front end.

Comment: @ITried In Java you can do [`str = str.replaceAll("a+", "a");`](http://rextester.com/AJWT80445)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a slightly modified answer to what was posted earlier:

```js
var str = "aaaa aaa aaaaaa safsd a a a aaaa";
str = str.replace(/a{2,}/g, "a");
console.log(str);
```

The difference here is that we only do a replacement for *two* or more `a`'s.  A single `a` does not need to be involved.